# Mapping symmetrical relationships in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a User table and a UserRelation table (simplified example). A User may have 0 or more relations to other users. The UserRelation table has two columns: user1 and user2. Currently I have this mapping in User.hbm.xml:

```
<set name="userRelations">
  <key column="user1" />
  <one-to-many class="UserRelation" />
</set>
```

However, the relations are symmetrical, so what I (think I) would like to do is something like this:

```
<set name="userRelations">
  <key column="user1 OR user2" />
  <one-to-many class="UserRelation" />
</set>
```

Is something like this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way? I could always add two rows for each relation (Alice -> Bob and Bob -> Alice), but that seems a bit redundant. Another option would be to have two different sets, but that doesn't feel particularly intuitive either.

Comment: Just normalize the *order* in which the two ids are stored in the link, and you don't ever have to worry about how to find a hypothetical link.

Comment: @KilianFoth I guess that would work if I just wanted to check if there is a relationship between two specific users, but what if I want to get all relations for a user? Or am I just being thick and not getting your comment?

Comment: No, that's just what I meant: store (e.g.) the lower id in `left_link` and the higher id in `right_link`. And you're right, that will require two JOINs instead of one when you want to *enumerate* soneone's links - that's the price to be paid for the space you save by normalizing the relation to be auto-symmetrical.

Comment: @KilianFoth Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: @KilianFoth Given the OP's positive response, I'd suggest posting that as an answer.